# how to move to first node when using XPathNodeIterator

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML file that I am iterating through searching for specific matches to a list of criteria.
When I search through the whole file, I either find or don't find the criteria. If I find it great move onto next criteria, if I don't find it, I write the criteria in a file.

Now there are probably better ways to do this but here is what I have atm.
Cut down version of code.

```
        Dim xDocSource As New XPathDocument(sourceFile.Text)
        Dim xNavSource As XPathNavigator = xDocSource.CreateNavigator()
        Dim xIteratorSource As XPathNodeIterator = xNavSource.Select("/MIBVIEW/DATA/ATTRIBUTE")

        Dim xDocMaster As New XPathDocument(checkFile.Text)
        Dim xNavMaster As XPathNavigator = xDocMaster.CreateNavigator()
        Dim xIteratorMaster As XPathNodeIterator = xNavMaster.Select("/MIBVIEW/DATA/ATTRIBUTE")

        Do
            xIteratorMaster.MoveNext()

            While (xIteratorSource.MoveNext())
            "...process attributes..."
            End While

        Loop Until xIteratorMaster.CurrentPosition = xIteratorMaster.Count
```

What I am getting, right now, is the while loop remembers which node it was at and continues from there.

So with xIteratorSource how do I get it to point to the first node?
As far as I can see, XPathNodeIterator does not have any functions to do it.
I also tried using xNavSource (XPathNavigator) but I can't make it work.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please! Maybe .MoveTO or something like that!

Comment: Reading the docs, suggest to me best process it first copy it to an array/list then you're free to iterate over that as you please.  Also note it looks like you've got two nested loops there, one at least seems a little redundant.

Comment: All in all, if possible, would probably look at doing this by deserializing your xml to a collection of a user defined type.  Makes the whole handling xml data thing a lot more flexible

Comment: I'm really puzzled by this since it's not obvious what `xIteratorSource` is for. Your code queries two documents ("source" and "master"), but you only do anything with the "master" document, and there's no indication of what "source" is for.

Comment: @Conal Tuohy, I am using comparing each line of the master against each line of the source for a match. If it matches, use next line of master, if no match save line to a diff file then goto next line of master. I can post more code if required.

Comment: @Hursey, I hope my comment to Conal made it a little clearer what I am doing. So I am new to parsing XML. I am astounded that using 3 different classes and I can't use any of them to start at the beginning of the file/list. Thank you for the suggestion of using array/list. I will try and see if it will work for my situation.

Comment: You are trying to list all the `/MIBVIEW/DATA/ATTRIBUTE` elements in the `master` file which don't correspond to a `/MIBVIEW/DATA/ATTRIBUTE` element in the `source` file? Then I agree with @Hursey you should read the `source` into an array or list or some other convenient data structure, rather than attempt to repeatedly reuse the XPath iterator (if that's what you were thinking)

Comment: @Conal Tuohy, that is exactly what I am trying to do! I will give the array a try. Get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found a solution and here is the code. The magic line of code I was missing was xNavSource.MoveToFirstChild(). It is most of the code. The DIMs have been left out.

```
    Dim xDocMaster As New XPathDocument(checkFile.Text)
    Dim xNavMaster As XPathNavigator = xDocMaster.CreateNavigator()
    Dim xIteratorMaster As XPathNodeIterator = xNavMaster.Select("/MIBVIEW/DATA/ATTRIBUTE")

    Dim xDocSource As New XPathDocument(sourceFile.Text)
    Dim xNavSource As XPathNavigator = xDocSource.CreateNavigator()

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dFile.Text, "")
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(dFile.Text, True)

    xNavSource.MoveToRoot() 'Move to the first child node (comment field).
    xNavSource.MoveToFirstChild()
    xNavSource.MoveToChild("DATA", "")

    Do
        xIteratorMaster.MoveNext()
        xNavSource.MoveToFirstChild() '<--- the magic line of code
        ProgressBar1.Value = 100 * xIteratorMaster.CurrentPosition / xIteratorMaster.Count

        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
            'Debug.Print("CurrentSource: " & xIteratorSource.CurrentPosition & ", SourceCount: " & xIteratorSource.Count) 'current position -------------------------------

            Moid = xIteratorMaster.Current.GetAttribute("oid", "")
            Mlabel = xIteratorMaster.Current.GetAttribute("label", "")
            Mvalue = xIteratorMaster.Current.GetAttribute("value", "")
            Soid = xNavSource.GetAttribute("oid", "")
            Slabel = xNavSource.GetAttribute("label", "")
            Svalue = xNavSource.GetAttribute("value", "")

            If Moid = Soid Then
                If Svalue = Mvalue Then
                    'Exit For
                    xNavSource.MoveToFirst()
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    file.WriteLine(Soid & "; " & Slabel & "; " & Svalue)
                    'Exit For
                    xNavSource.MoveToFirst()
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Else
                'try again
            End If
        Loop While xNavSource.MoveToNext

        'Debug.Print(Soid & ", " & Slabel & ", " & Svalue) 'current position -------------------------------
    Loop Until xIteratorMaster.CurrentPosition = xIteratorMaster.Count
```